# Updating a function stored in a ref, using useRef

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It appears you can't just supply a function object to be stored in a ref, meaning we need something like:

```
const myHook = () => {
  const cb = useRef(() => noop)
  // ...
  console.log(cb.current) // This is how you get access to the function object

  useEffect(() => {
    // How can I update the function object stored inside the `cb` ref?
  })
}
```

But how can I update the function object associated with the ref?

Comment: `cb.current = () => {}`

Comment: It's that simple?

Comment: According to these blog posts, you don't want to update refs inside of useEffect hooks:
https://medium.com/@teh_builder/ref-objects-inside-useeffect-hooks-eb7c15198780

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-debounce-example/

Refs are mutable meeaning they won't work in the dependency array for useEffect.

Comment: @opike there is nothing about a dependency array in the question

Comment: @Konrad - ok, but it's rare to have a useEffect without any dependencies or an empty dependecy array. Without more information about the specific use case, it's difficult to make a determination if it makes sense here.

Comment: I want an "instance variable" for my hook, with a value of a function. This value changes over time and is a function that cancels a timer. Following Konrad's suggestion, works.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by using the `useCallback` hook, this returns a memoized version of the function, which means it will only be recreated when the dependencies inside the `useCallback` argument change. If passed an empty array as the argument, the function will only be created once, similar to the "componentDidMount" lifecycle method.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const newFunction = useCallback(() => {
    console.log("Updated function");
  }, []);
  cb.current = newFunction;
}, []);
```

Comment: It's not possible to use `useCallback` inside `useEffect`

Comment: but we can use regular function definition inside useEffect?